# view is not instantiating

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm doing a tutorial and my problem is at the very bottom of my code where you instantiate a new App.Views.AddTask view it's not working because when you click submit the page reloads and the e.preventDefault() isn't working. If I just type in the console new App.Views.AddTask then the e.preventDefault() works and the page doesn't submit what is cause this to not work correctly. my problem is in the adTaskView variable at the bottom.

```
    (function() {

    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {}

    };


    window.template = function(id) {
        return  _.template($('#' + id).html());
    }

    App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
        validate: function(attrs) {
            if(!$.trim(attrs.title)) {
                return 'A task requires a valid title.'
            }
        }
    });

    App.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.Task
    })

    App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',

        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);

            return this;
        },

        addOne: function(task) {
            var taskView = new App.Views.Task({model: task});

            this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
        }
    })

    App.Views.Task = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',

        template: template('taskTemplate'),


        initialize: function() {

            this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
            this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
        },

        events: {
            'click .edit': 'editTask',
            'click .delete': 'destroy'
        },

        editTask: function() {
            var newTask = prompt('What would you likje to change the text to?', this.model.get('title'));

            if(!$.trim(newTask)) return;

            this.model.set('title', newTask);
        },

        destroy: function() {
            this.model.destroy();           
        },

        remove: function() {
            this.$el.remove();
        },

        render: function() {
            var template = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
            this.$el.html( template );
            return this;
        }
    })

    window.tasksCollection = new App.Collections.Tasks([
        {
            title: 'Go tot the store',
            priority: 4
        },
        {
            title: 'Feed the dog',
            priority: 2
        },
    ]);

    // PROBLEM WITH THIS PART
    App.Views.AddTask = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#addtask',

        events: {
            'submit': 'submit'
        },

        initialize: function() {

        },

        submit: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log('hit');
            var newTaskTitle = $(e.currentTarget).find('input[type=text]').val();
            var task = new App.Models.Task({ title: newTaskTitle});
            this.collection.add(task);

        }

    });


    var tasksView = new App.Views.Tasks({ collection: tasksCollection});
    var addTaskView = new App.Views.AddTask({ collection: tasksCollection });

    $(document).ready(function() {                               
        $('.tasks').html(tasksView.render().el);
    });     

})();
```

Form:

```
<form action="" id="addtask">
    <input type="text" name="task" id="task" />
    <button type="submit">Add Task</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
events: {
    'submit': 'submit'
},
```

You add event to `submit` element on the page. But You wanted:

```
events: {
    'button[type=submit]': 'submit'
},
```

or

```
events: {
    'button': 'submit'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`submit` event is too late to prevent the submission. You should bind the handler to `click` event instead.

```
 events: {
        'click': 'submit'
    },
```